# Python update a dictionary of array

Tags: python, arrays, optimization, dictionary

I have an empty 'numpy.ndarray' to update.

```
import numpy as np
my_grid =  np.zeros((5, 5))

# stat 
parse = "max","min","avg"

# create a dictionary for each element of parse 
grid_stat = {}
for arg in parse:
    grid_stat[arg] = my_grid


 grid_stat 
{'avg': array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]]),
 'max': array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]]),
 'min': array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])}
```

I wish to update with new value each grid in the dictionary (it will be part of a loop)
ex: `on dy = 0, dx = 0, max= 100, min= 50, avg = 75`

```
grid_stat 
    {'avg': array([[ 75.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
           [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
           [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
           [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
           [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]]),
     'max': array([[ 100.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
           [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
           [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
           [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
           [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]]),
     'min': array([[ 50.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
           [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
           [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
           [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
           [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])}
```

i tried an easy solution

`grid_stat['avg'][0,0] = 100` but also for max and min the value updated is 100

```
grid_stat
{'avg': array([[ 100.,    0.,    0.,    0.,    0.],
       [   0.,    0.,    0.,    0.,    0.],
       [   0.,    0.,    0.,    0.,    0.],
       [   0.,    0.,    0.,    0.,    0.],
       [   0.,    0.,    0.,    0.,    0.]]),
 'max': array([[ 100.,    0.,    0.,    0.,    0.],
       [   0.,    0.,    0.,    0.,    0.],
       [   0.,    0.,    0.,    0.,    0.],
       [   0.,    0.,    0.,    0.,    0.],
       [   0.,    0.,    0.,    0.,    0.]]),
 'min': array([[ 100.,    0.,    0.,    0.,    0.],
       [   0.,    0.,    0.,    0.,    0.],
       [   0.,    0.,    0.,    0.,    0.],
       [   0.,    0.,    0.,    0.,    0.],
       [   0.,    0.,    0.,    0.,    0.]])}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I suggested in the comments to the last question, you probably want to use

```
for arg in parse:
    grid_stat[arg] = my_grid.copy()
```

instead of

```
for arg in parse:
    grid_stat[arg] = my_grid
```

sets each value of `grid_stat` to the *very same* array, the one called `my_grid`.  It doesn't make three separate arrays of the same shape and contents.  You can confirm this by using `id` or `is`:

```
>>> id(my_grid)
4325774752
>>> id(grid_stat['max'])
4325774752
>>> id(grid_stat['avg'])
4325774752
>>> id(grid_stat['min'])
4325774752
>>> my_grid is grid_stat['max']
True
>>> grid_stat['max'] is grid_stat['avg']
True
```

etc.

Comment: Thanks DSM but sorry i did't get the suggestion for my problem.

Comment: @Gianni: don't use `grid_stat[arg] = my_grid`.  Use `grid_stat[arg] = my_grid.copy()`.

Comment: It works, thanks. Sorry if i ask about .copy() and why it works using copy? ( i need to improve my skills)

Comment: This is discussed in [this section](http://www.scipy.org/Tentative_NumPy_Tutorial#head-1529ae93dd5d431ffe3a1001a4ab1a394e70a5f2) of the numpy tutorial.